# Syntax error when assign a variable for top clause in sql server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, declare, clause

I need to get top 10, top 100 records like this from a table. But I need to assign the value for top clause such as 10 or 100 in a variable.

But when I give like below, it gives an syntax error "Incorrect syntax near '@numberofRecords'.".

```
DECLARE @numberofRecords INT
SELECT @numberofRecords = ConfigValue FROM tblConfigItems (NOLOCK) WHERE configName = 'TopRecords'

SELECT TOP @numberofRecords [ID],TypeID, MessageType, operationDate
FROM NotifyTbl (NOLOCK)
wHERE STATUS IN ('1', '2')
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid dinamic SQL. Just use this:

```
SELECT TOP (@numberofRecords) [ID],TypeID, MessageType, operationDate
FROM NotifyTbl (NOLOCK)
wHERE STATUS IN ('1', '2')
```

You need at least SQL 2005 to have it working. Yes () does the trick.

Comment: I tried this in SQL Server 2008 R2, its not working.

Comment: @thevan I tried this in SQL Server 2008 R2, it works. maybe you could supply some technical information and not only 'is not working'. any error message?

Comment: I tried it to before giving solution.
Maybe is database in compatibility mode SQL 2000?

Comment: It gives error such as " Incorrect syntax near '(' ". & I am also using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: What about compatibility mode of database? Just because, even if it works, I consider less elegant and with more difficulties in troubleshoting a dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 2):

You could use dynamic SQL

```
exec('SELECT TOP ' + @numberofRecords + ' [ID],TypeID, MessageType, operationDate
      FROM NotifyTbl (NOLOCK)
      wHERE STATUS IN (''1'', ''2'')')
```